# Magento 2.1: Adding Custom Css to Admin Ui Component Form

Tags: magento-2.1, css, forms, uicomponent, fieldsets

I invested a couple of hours to get a solution to figure out , that how can we customize the M2 admin form - for the sake of clarity please see the below screenshot:

### The default admin form fieldsets appear in the following fashion:

[image]

### My goal is to customize it to the one given below in the image:

by adding custom css to the fieldsets..

[image]

I found this item :

```
    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">
    admin__field-wide</item>
```

Can any one suggest how this can be done or what is the proper way of adding custom css to the admin forms.

Comment: seems <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field-wide</item> - working